# hyperledger composer - cyclic API detected

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am trying to implement permissions in multi-user mode on composer and for that my ACL file looks like:

```
rule R1 {
  description: "..."
  participant(p): "org.example.SampleParticipantOne"
  operation: ALL
  resource(d): "org.example.SampleParticipantThree"         // resource is of participant type
  condition: (p.sampleRelation.getIdentifier() === d.sampleRelation.getIdentifier())
  action: ALLOW
}

rule R2 {
  description: "..."
  participant(p): "org.example.SampleParticipantOne"
  operation: ALL
  resource(d): "org.example.SampleParticipantThree"
  condition: (!(p.sampleRelation.getIdentifier() === d.sampleRelation.getIdentifier()))
  action: DENY
}

rule SystemACL {
  description:  "System ACL to permit all access"
  participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.Participant"
  operation: ALL
  resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
  action: ALLOW
}

rule NetworkAdminUser {
  description: "Grant business network administrators full access to user resources"
  participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin"
  operation: ALL
  resource: "**"
  action: ALLOW
}

rule NetworkAdminSystem {
  description: "Grant business network administrators full access to system resources"
  participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin"
  operation: ALL
  resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
  action: ALLOW
}

rule AllowAll {
  description: "..."
  participant: "org.example.**"
  operation: ALL
  resource: "org.example.**"
  action: ALLOW
}
```

and underlying models look like:

```
namespace org.example

participant SampleParticipantOne identified by id {
  o String id
  --> SampleParticipantTwo sampleRelation
  o string someMoreFields
}

participant SampleParticipantTwo identified by id {
  o String id
  o string someMoreFields
}

participant SampleParticipantThree identified by id {
  o String id
  --> SampleParticipantTwo sampleRelation
  o string someMoreFields
}
```

but when I try to get SampleParticipantThree while i carry SampleParticipantOne card, it returns me empty array and docker logs of peer show error something like:

`ERROR    :AccessController         :checkRule()               Error: Cyclic ACL Rule detected, rule condition is invoking the same rule`

can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the rule `R2` because when you have rules in `permissions.acl` file everything is blocked then you give permissions, so you already have allowed participant `SimpleParticipantOne` to access `SampleParticipantThree` resource.

I have also removed the `SystemACL` rule. That was also conflicting with `NetworkAdminSystem`.

Try this:

```
rule R1 {
  description: "..."
  participant(p): "org.example.SampleParticipantOne"
  operation: ALL
  resource(d): "org.example.SampleParticipantThree"         // resource is of participant type
  condition: (p.sampleRelation.getIdentifier() === d.sampleRelation.getIdentifier())
  action: ALLOW
}

rule NetworkAdminUser {
  description: "Grant business network administrators full access to user resources"
  participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin"
  operation: ALL
  resource: "**"
  action: ALLOW
}

rule NetworkAdminSystem {
  description: "Grant business network administrators full access to system resources"
  participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin"
  operation: ALL
  resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
  action: ALLOW
}

rule AllowAll {
  description: "..."
  participant: "org.example.**"
  operation: ALL
  resource: "org.example.**"
  action: ALLOW
}
```

Comment: systemACL is required system rule and removing the rule two also does not make any change, problem is still same. anyway thanks for responding :)